# How to check and return string or return false and exit if statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Working in Rails 4.2 and Ruby 2.3.3

I'm dealing with an API that has an error fiend in certain circumstances but not in other circumstances. I would like to check to see if that error key exists and, if yes, downcase it and search for the existence of something. Like this where `parsed` is a hash:

```
# parsed could be either:
# {error: "Email does not exist"}
# or 
# {result: ... }

return true  if parsed.dig('error').downcase!.include?('email does not exist') # refactor
```

I can see dig returns nil in this case. Is there any way I can tell that if statement to exit if nil? Maybe force it to false and exit without adding a lot of ceremony code?

I know I could do something like this but it seems cumbersome:

```
unless parsed['error'].nil?
  return true  if parsed.dig('error').downcase!.include?('email does not exist') # refactor
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
parsed.dig('error').to_s.downcase.include?('email does not exist')
```

`to_s` converts `nil` to `''`. No need for `downcase!` because you don't need to mutate the original object and because it [returns `nil` if no changes were made](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/String/downcase%21); just use `downcase`.

Note that your example uses symbolized keys and your code uses stringified keys, so it'll never match:

```
parsed = {error: "Email does not exist"} # key is symbolized
parsed.dig('error').to_s.downcase.include?('email does not exist') # key is stringified
=> false

parsed = {error: "Email does not exist"} # key is symbolized
parsed.dig(:error).to_s.downcase.include?('email does not exist') # key is symbolized
=> true
```

Since you're using Rails, you can make your life a little easier with indifferent access. This allows hash keys to be accessed by string or by symbol:

```
parsed.with_indifferent_access.dig('error').to_s.downcase.include?('email does not exist')
=> true
parsed.with_indifferent_access.dig(:error).to_s.downcase.include?('email does not exist')
=> true
```

Using this gives you some flexibility.